# Stored Procedure to Web Service

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services

I would like to know if there is an automatic (or effortless) way to map SQL Server stored procedures to web services?

The problem is, I need to allow a third party application to interact/integrate data with an ERP system. This ERP provides several stored procedures to do that. Those stored procedures also contain validation and tons of business logic.

But, this external app prefers to go through web services.

So, the first approach is to create a web service and map each stored procedure to a method (or may be split in different endpoints) but, I don't know is there is some tool, if it can be done using Entity Framework, etc.

Comment: What is so special about WCF?

Answer (score 0):

You could write something yourself using SMO (Sql management objects), if we are talking about 2 stored procs it may not be worth it but if its 100...

this is a demonstration to use SMO. the same idea could be used for writing out your service contract etc.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Server srv = new Server("serverName");
            Database db = srv.Databases["myDBName"];

            foreach (StoredProcedure proc in db.StoredProcedures)
            {

                StringBuilder methodWriter = new StringBuilder();

                methodWriter.Append("public void " + proc.Name + "(");

                foreach(Parameter param in proc.Parameters)
                {
                    string csharpData = string.Empty;

                    if (param.DataType == DataType.DateTime) { csharpData = "DateTime " + param.Name; }
                    //...

                    methodWriter.Append(csharpData + ", ");

                }

                methodWriter.Append("){}");

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you recommending that the OP create an ASMX service? ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: why the down vote? that would write a web method for every proc in his database for the method to call. Certainly not all that painful

Comment: it was an illustration of smo, not a recommendation to use the any specific service technology. he could very easily spit it out any way he chooses.

Comment: Or, you could modify your code to generate a WCF service, and get an upvote from me. Your choice.

Comment: "Nothing is painless" is a comment, not an answer.